What function does 得 have in the phrase 水枪射向正着火的床上被得?
What function does 得 have in the phrase 水枪射向正着火的床上被得? see https://www.163.com/dy/article/J024MOFQ0543A3A8.html

there is no such word(被得) in Chinese and the true word may be "被单" mentioned by PdotWang.
The reason why the author wrote a wrong word may be that the pinyin prefix for both 得(dé) and 单(dān) is d. So 得 here is just a mistake for author's carelessness.
被单 means bed sheet and the sentence means sprinkler water was shot at the sheet that was on fire.

Does it not seem that the article would be be put in by some professional typist working at the news site in question. Would they use an input method based on pinyin, when methods based on shape are well known to be much faster.

I think it was a typo of 被褥 (bedding)

Professional typist may input wrong words, and the article is not written by professional typists, you could find the origin writer by clicking the character "路之意" under the title. 网易新闻(Netease News, the site that the article was put on) allows people put their own news article on it if people pass the move-in application. As for the input method, though there is a method based on strokes called 五笔, but pinyin input method is much more common.

I, as a native speaker of the Chinese language for more than 50 years, believe that the writing of the sentence is wrong. I guess it would be “床上被单”。

You might NOT notice the message below whole document :

特别声明：以上内容(如有图片或视频亦包括在内)为自媒体平台“网易号”用户上传并发布，本平台仅提供信息存储服务。
Notice: The content above (including the pictures and videos if any)
is uploaded and posted by a user of NetEase Hao, which is a social
media platform and only provides information storage services.

This website is NOT news web site, more like a new story one.
